# If the Russian regime is so popular, why does it need to invest into limiting freedom of expression?

Tags: russian-federation, freedom-of-speech, privacy

According to [this article](https://www.hrw.org/news/2017/08/01/russia-new-legislation-attacks-internet-anonymity), Putin has signed two laws that further limit freedom of expression (law source):

> Two new laws in Russia jeopardize the privacy and security of internet
> users and aim to further control Russians’ freedom of expression,
> Human Rights Watch said today.
>
> The legislation, signed into law by
> President Vladimir Putin on July 30, 2017, bans anonymous use of
> online messenger applications and prohibits the use of software to
> allow users to circumvent internet censorship. The new laws are part
> of Russia’s widespread crackdown on online expression, in violation of
> human rights law and democratic safeguards.

This is not something new according to [this article](https://www.hrw.org/report/2017/07/18/online-and-all-fronts/russias-assault-freedom-expression):

> Since 2012, the Russian authorities have intensified a crackdown on
> freedom of expression, selectively casting certain kinds of criticism
> of the government as threats to state security and public stability
> and introducing significant restrictions to online expression and
> invasive surveillance of online activity.
>
> While new restrictions on freedom of expression appear to target
> political opposition or civic groups, they affect all Russians.
> Curbing free speech denies a voice to anyone dissatisfied with the
> ongoing economic crisis or even mildly critical of Russia’s foreign
> policy.

However, according [to Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/06/22/overwhelming-majority-russians-support-putins-handling-world/), Putin seems to be a very popular leader, popularity that might be envied by other important leaders such as Donald Trump or Theresa May:

> Russian President Vladimir Putin is viewed favourably by a big
> majority of his citizens, according to new research.
>
> A study conducted by the Pew Research Center shows that 87 per cent of
> Russians have confidence in Putin’s ability to do the right thing on
> world affairs.
>
> The immense support bestowed upon him is a notch higher than many
> other politicians, making him one of the most popular leaders in the
> world.

**Question:** So, if the Russian regime is so popular, why does it need to invest into limiting freedom of expression?

Those against it represent a rather small minority that does not seem to pose a serious danger to the current regime.

Comment: You're confusing the cause and the effect, sorry. The reason those against it are a minority - at least one of big reasons - is the information control. Think how popular GWB or Trump would be without antagonistic press blowing up every single negative thing (and inventing some). With less effect, presumably Obama would have been more popular without Fox News and right wing blogs, though their influence is far less just by volume. If every bad thing about Putin/Russia was known to all Russian citizens, it would impact his popularity and generate feedback loop where he defends himself.

Comment: @user4012 - so, the huge popularity is an artificial one. I do not know what to do with the question. Your comment is almost an answer that shows my false premise (which is a valid answer IMO). On the other hand, it is not clear if this kind of questions are valid (on-topic).

Comment: It's 100% ontopic, though I'm afraid a GOOD answer may require a book or at least a large series of articles. I tried to post a short one but am not fully satisfied with it. I would urge you strongly to read whatever free publications/analysis Stratfor has on the topic as well as their podcasts. They aren't the only view out there but they are an influential and popular view that is often right in the predictions.

Comment: "Question: So, if the Russian regime is so popular, why does it need to invest into limit freedom of expression?" At least we should raise the same question about germany, france and the UK where doors are kicked in for "abusive language". Orwellian, isn't it?

Comment: That's what we call false equivalence. Being taken to court for advocating violence against people is different from being taken to court (or rather, just taken) for advocating freedom for people.

Comment: no, it's not false equivalence, as it's the same the US is executing on twitter, facebook and the EU even on every other media. https://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/886641/Brexit-news-BBC-Question-Time-divorce-bill-European-Union-Ukip-Henry-Bolton it's all about containment

Comment: The EU and the US have several similar laws ... it's standard anti russian propaganda as usual. Germany has passed an even more agressive law against freedom of speech in the internet this year: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netzwerkdurchsetzungsgesetz

Comment: @user4012 - Agree with Obama and GWB...but Trumps popularity is in part with his willingness to fight with media, one could argue without it he would be less popular as we'd only have his record to judge him by and not his fight vs the establishment to boost him (Trump is a harsh contrast to any other, Putin included....Trump thrives on the negative coverage and it draws his supports to his defense).

Comment: @Twelfth - there might be something to that. I know plenty of people who see the main value of Trump in smashing the media (heck, I'm probably close to that camp, unsurprisingly)

Comment: It is the obvious difference between defensive and attacking strategies. Russian measures are not in any way directed at its internal population, but rather against the well-know aggressors: the US regime, the UK regime and their vassal regimes. There's no connection to the "popularity" or "unpopularity" of any kind there.

Comment: @image - The European Union does have many such laws. The U.S., not so much. It's entirely legal to criticize the president, even with intimations of violence (Ted Nugent, Kathy Griffin). It's legal to promote violent ideologies, so long as they don't present a clear and present (i.e. immediate) danger (various neo-Nazi groups, anarchists, war hawks, etc.) Hate speech against any group is legal (though there may still be social consequences).

Comment: One more fact to consider: there has *never* been an opposition TV channel in Russia that gained any noticable traction. Simple Russian people really *believe* that TV can't lie.

Comment: @Barafu - Or Putin shuts them down. ;)

Comment: Why "regime"? Looks to me that it is a democratically elected government, and even one liked by the population

Comment: I question the use of 'popular'. A friend of mine once said of a place 'this would be far more popular if there weren't so many people here'...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

TL;DR: The answer to "why" is because limits on freedom of expression makes the regime less disliked (your question is confusing cause and effect - the popularity of the regime is a consequence of limits on free expression) and reduces both the effort required to stay in power and the likelihood that it falls out of power. It's as simple as that.

---

Stratfor (pretty much any of their publications about USSR/Russia internal geopolitics would serve as citation) usually stresses that this is due to the combination of the following factors:

1. Russia is - and has been since 17th or 18th century - a federated empire (loosely using the term, I'm open to a more precise technical term). It is extremely heterogeneous, especially ethnically (native Slav Russians are an overall 80% majority in RF but not in all regions; and were even smaller in USSR and Czarist empire, with total all Slavs only being 75%); but also ideologically.

   As such, there are very strong political centrifugal forces; which have succeeded in breaking the empire apart before (in 1917, and in 1991).
2. Russia has unfavorable economic factors - the lack of inter-country navigation combined with out of date technological base combined with entrenched culture of corruption means far more relative expenses and greater friction in economic activity and far lower average standards of living (not exactly helped by 70 years of Socialism; but Russia was economically screwed over by the Czars for centuries before that; and by post-Soviet governments after that too).

   This means that the government can't easily buy the good will of the large percent of the populace with economic satisfaction, unless oil prices are booming - as happened in 1970s under Brezhnev or 2000s under Putin.

These two factors combined means that Russia has to expend far more effort at keeping itself whole and its population in line, compared to, say, USA.

Internal security and lack of political freedoms are two major levers towards that effort. They are among the major reasons Putin is so popular - nothing damaging to his regime is allowed to be known by the masses; and no popular opponents are allowed to gel to challenge him beyond a couple of tame ones.

Comment: I think those two points are a good summary that explains why Russian politicians are virtually forced into reducing political freedom. It is really useful for those that wish to have a basic understanding of why Russia does not afford the road to liberal democracy or something similar.

Comment: @Alexei - I don't buy that anyone's being forced here. These are factors that makes things easier for a would-be dictator, not things that make dictatorship desirable. And of course further giving the lie to this, in Putin's case anyway, is Putin's enormous personal wealth, largely acquired through illegal or unethical means. If Putin were more purely motivated by altruism toward the Russian people, he would not be enriching himself in such a manner.

Comment: In other words, I agree with the first portion of the answer. Power, power, power. Putin doesn't want to lose power, like many other individual throughout history, whatever their forms of government, and so he does what he can to stay in power. But that doesn't mean it's good for Russia, or for the people of Russia.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - unfortunately, many people in Russia disagree. Heck, look at Stalin's popularity there. Russian cultural psyche likes a "strong hand" - and it makes sense, decision making and personal responsibility are generally hard and you need to be nudged into liking that effort.

Comment: Great answer. But you also forget some points. There are several factors like cultural differences which may explain that democracy is less popular in Russia.  And most of all, Putin rebuilt a country in severe crisis into a feared world superpower.  Moreover the west by sanctions or type of attacks may federate the russian peoples against an external ennemy. The russian regime may be strenghtened by his own opponents.

Comment: "the popularity of the regime is a consequence of limits on free expression". That's less and less true. Many russians can read english and are one click away from our "mainstream medias".

Comment: @Alexei The second point in the answer is, at this point, a symptom of the lack of political freedom. Those who are the perpetrators of corruption could be ousted by political freedom, they have a vested interest in keeping the status quo. They are only "forced" into reducing freedom in the sense that they would potentially lose their status of power without the limitations on freedom.

Answer (score 20):

That's how successful Autocracy works. Inspire radical nationalism where possible (see: [Cult of Personality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cult_of_personality)), put the fear of god into the rest. You can see this today in [China](https://www.cato.org/blog/china-cracks-down-ideas-music-advertising) and [Turkey](http://time.com/4429177/turkeys-president-is-using-the-coup-attempt-to-crack-down-on-the-media/) in addition to Russia. Xi in China touts [a comparable approval score](https://thediplomat.com/2014/12/the-worlds-most-popular-leader-chinas-president-xi/) to Putin in this article's calculations, and [Erdogan is reported similarly](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-08-11/erdogan-s-approval-rating-soars-in-turkey-following-coup-attempt). All of these countries have oppressive regimes where anyone who vocally disapproves of the country is [liable](https://www.theguardian.com/artanddesign/2011/apr/04/ai-weiwei-missing-chinese-police) to [disappear](http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/features/2014/12/disappearing-crimea-anti-russia-activists-201412110405525656.html).

Why are approval rates so high then? The cost of voicing disapproval is much greater than the benefit gained from opposition, any media that isn't saying their country is the best in the world is shut down, and relatively speaking the living conditions of each country aren't bad enough to warrant revolt. In other words, the 'popularity' is a result of the limited freedom, it's not inherent to the regime.

Answer (score 15):

I'll take a jab at what the **official** explanation for restricting the freedom of speech is, from most sensible to the least:

> Democracy is overrated, we need a strong leader to run the country efficiently

This argument is absolutely true, *in theory*. A benevolent dictator can be a lot more effective than popularly elected leaders as they can implement the best policies with little regard to what the opposition says. China's success shows it's absolutely possible to achieve amazing results without even pretending to be a democracy.

But *in practice*, no dictator is ever benevolent in the full sense of the word and many are downright malevolent and corrupt to the core. Even China is facing a lot of issues over nepotism and corruption, which would be easier to prevent in an open society.

> If we have the freedom of speech our enemies will use it against us

This is true in part, as even the leaders of the US and the EU admit that foreign actors are successfully influencing domestic elections, both through direct monetary contributions (see [Marine Le Pen's party and Russia](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-39478066)) and indirect manipulation of the public opinion (Russia Today, spreading "fake news").

However dictators conveniently forget that it's often far easier for foreign states to influence the local politics in non-transparent systems, as it's easier to obfuscate bribes to high level officials. Likewise it's easier to combat "fake news" when you have a developed media ecosystem of your own.

> We don't need free elections as the opposition sucks anyway

Here the dictators conveniently forget that all viable candidates are promptly jailed (see Navalny and Khodorkovsky in Russia), exiled (Dalai Lama in China) or outright killed (Boris Nemtsov in Russia). But unfortunately people who don't have access to open media fail to see the holes in this argument so many actually believe that no good competition can run against the great leader.

Comment: Navalny never served any real jail time

Comment: It would be nice to link to Russia Today or a Putin speech and make each one of the banners a direct quote. Or remove at least the bolding from "official" at the start.

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev he's been in jail plenty of times, the longest stretch being 1 month. And his brother is serving a 5 year sentence.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt the problem is that most sources for this are in Russian and Putin himself rarely says those things *directly*. I'm basing my post on following Russian politics for the past 15 years.

Comment: I very much like the idea of playing devil's advocate, but according to a sizable portion of the US media and political actors, Russia was able to influence (some say manipulate, others reach for "steal") the election despite the hyper-developed media system. It appears that it's either not a deterrent for fake news, or those people are spreading fake news, while they ought to be a deterrent against it.

Comment: @JonathanReez a month in jail, while surely unpleasant for him, didn’t really hinder his political activity or personal life in any way and can’t be compared to Khodorkovsky’s 10 years

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev yes it does. He is now inable to become a candidate in the presidential election as he's a former convict. And he can be thrown into jail at any time.

Comment: Err... if you call Boris Nemtsov "a canditdate", then you don't know anything about Russia.

Comment: @Spc_555 unfortunately things have gotten worse for Navalny over the past year...